# Fix line width Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-code

for some reason Visual Studio Code is giving a little space to write the code then it wraps to the other line. I have tried incrementing "Word Wrap Column" to 160 but no effect. Can you please tell me how to reset or redefine this setting. Thanks.
[image]

Comment: I don't see wrapped lines in your image

Comment: you are right, it is the formatting that I can't change